# Запрос на выборку дат в MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста как в MS ACCESS с помощью sql запроса создать запрос на выборку дат относительно сегодняшней даты?
Например есть таблица контакты. В ней есть атрибут дата_рождения. И нам надо сделать запрос который выведет поля у которых день рождения будет в течении следующих двух дней, относительно сегодняшней даты. (в общем наподобие этой штукенции в контакте)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком виде храните даты в базе? Какой тип? Приведите фрагмент из дизайнера таблицы с датами, а также желательно фрагмент данных.

Comment: Еще раз повторяю, Вам никто не сможет помочь, пока не покажете в каком виде храните даты в базе? Хоть сам файл выложите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM [Контакты]
    WHERE [дата_рождения] IS NOT NULL
        AND DATEADD("yyyy", DATEDIFF("yyyy", [дата_рождения], DATE()), [дата_рождения]) BETWEEN DATE() AND DATEADD("d", 2, DATE())
```

Comment: "Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора"

Comment: Пока возникает только подозрение на то, что [дата_рождения] имеет тип отличный от дата. Проверить пока что нет возможности ...

Comment: Ответ уже нашел, но с типом там все верно.

Comment: Проверил в ACCESS. Конструкция "DATEADD("yyyy", DATEDIFF("yyyy", [дата_рождения], DATE()), [дата_рождения]) BETWEEN DATE() AND DATEADD("d", 2, DATE())" ошибок не выдает.

Comment: А можете кинуть в качестве примера свою бд. Не могу понять почему ругается на тип данных.

Comment: В атрибуте "Дата_рождения" стоит дип данных дата/время. Формат поля не надо же менять?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/THQNLkvcqcRdS . База содержит одну таблицу из трех полей (Код, дата_рождения, ФИО) и один запрос на выбор тех, у кого день рождения в ближайшие 2 дня.

Comment: Создал новую БД и там заработало. Наверное что то натыкал. Спасибо за помощь kodv!!!!!!

Comment: Не подскажите что не так в моей БД. Когда создаю новую все работает. А когда пытаюсь применить данный способ к существующей БД (с теми же типами данных) ругается на "несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора". [Вот БД](https://yadi.sk/d/tmC7qzkkqcuYA). Запрос1.

Comment: Ошибка возникает из-за того, что для ряда строк birthday = NULL. В данном случае поможет добавление дополнительного условия AND birhtday IS NOT NULL. Отвечт сейчас подкорректирую: он этот аспект н учитывает.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT my_date
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE my_date >= #2016-03-30 00:00:00#
       AND my_date < #2016-04-02 00:00:00#;
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183180/select-query-with-date-condition) взял

Comment: Вообще ничего не выводит(

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, но помог мне такой код:
SELECT Дата_рождения
FROM контактные_лица
WHERE Дата_рождения Between DATE() And DATEADD("d",2,DATE());

Comment: Это был первый вариант, который я вам написал забыв подумать. Но он не должен работать правильно, так как на момент сейчас он будет выбирать только тех, кто родился с 31.03.2016 по 2.04.2016 (то есть, никого). Если человек родился, например, 01.04.1990, то, в соответствии с вашим условием, он в выборку не попадет. Поэтому в моем ответе и появилась конструкция, которая преобразует дату из 01.04.1990 в 01.04.2016. Хотя, если ваш запрос каким то магическим образом все таки работает правильно, то я вас с этим поздравляю.

Comment: Точно. Вы правы. Не учел